# Cannot access the site after changing admin password

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, admin

I have drupal 7 site hosted on bluehost.

After I changed the admin password, I got an error. I then tried to access the site, and I was able to do that, but it was very slow.

Now, I can't access the site as an administrator. It becomes even more weird: If I delete all history and cookies from the server, I can access the site; I can also login as an authenticated user.

When I try to log in as administrator, I get a white page or a "500 internal server" error. (It depends on the browser; I tried Chrome, FF and IE.) After I do that, I cannot access the site even as guest or authenticated user; only when I delete all the history and cookies, I can access the site as guest or authenticated user.

How can I fix this?

This is the error log the bluehost Representative gave me:

[15-Apr-2014 14:48:49 Europe/Helsinki] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function intel_path_filter_type_to_arg() in public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 814
Is it possiable this module has something to do with the issue? https://drupal.org/project/intel

I think I disable the google analytic api module. Maybe the problem is related to one of the Drupal SEO modules?

I am really not sure, and cannot connect my site..

Yesterday the site worked great! Restoring the site to yesterdays backup did not help - this is the weirdest thing!

**Update:** The problem was related to one of the two below (or both):

- the error from the intel module
- the session cache / cache

Now the site is working good, and the intelligence module is active. The weird thing that restoring the database did not fix the issue.

I am afraid to change the password again or disable the intel module. Do you think it can cause issues again?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable Drupal SEO module via database:

```
UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='seotools';
```

Disable this module if you have it: https://drupal.org/project/intel

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
How can I disable module through data base? I can access that and write the command you gave me?

Comment: You have to access to your database and execute the query above.

Comment: The problem was related to one of the two below (or both): The error from the intel module and The session cache / cache.
Currently the site is live and working great, but the Intel module is active currently and I don't know if to disable it or not.

The second thing we did (me and the nice guy that helped me) is to clear the cache and sessions cahce - which was problematic for me since I did not had access as admin. We used update.php after allowing every user to access it on the setting.php file (changed false to true), and clear the cache through mysql query. Can I disable the module now?

Comment: Yes, try to disable the module and then....check if your site works. In my opinion one of the two modules are breaking your web.

Answer (score 1):

All the information you need is in this link: https://drupal.org/node/1023428

Just use `./scripts/password-hash.sh newpwd` from your drupal root directory to generate a new hashed password and introduce this in the database using the following query

```
UPDATE users SET pass
='[HASHED PASSWORD]' WHERE uid = 1;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I already tried that: https://drupal.org/node/1556488
didn't help..
What you suggesting is the same?

Comment: It's not the same, but it should also work. Have you followed all the steps ?

Comment: I understood the problem was cache / session cache. The person helped me clear the cache using mysql quary on myphpadmin, and ran update.php after make it possible through he setting.php - since I did not had access to admin. Does it make sense that teh session cache was the problem? I am afraid to change the password now, after the problem recovered.. do you think I can change the password now, or I will have more problems?